# EasyNetQ - Consuming message from IAdvanceBus by non generic message

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, messaging, easynetq

Yes we can use auto subscriber functionality and normal subscribe method with this subscription id but this solution is bit ugly in RMQ queues and exchanges. It was difficult to follow and analyze the messages.

I use the advance bus and created my own exchanges and queues. I published successfully but the consuming part is bit disappointment. Currently, it uses this way:

```
    IAdvanceBus = bus.Advanced.Consume(queueName, registration => 
{
    registration.Add<MESSAGE1>((message, info) => { ProcessMessage(MESSAGE1) }) 
    registration.Add<MESSAGE2>((message, info) => { ProcessMessage(MESSAGE2) }) 
    registration.Add<MESSAGE3>((message, info) => { ProcessMessage(MESSAGE3) }) 
    registration.Add<MESSAGE4>((message, info) => { ProcessMessage(MESSAGE4) }) 
    registration.Add<MESSAGE5>((message, info) => { ProcessMessage(MESSAGE5) });
});
```

This is good but the problem if you have hundred listeners?

I checked the registration type [IHandlerRegistration](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/master/Source/EasyNetQ/Consumer/IHandlerRegistration.cs) it uses only generic one, can we have the none generic way?

Like :

```
    IAdvanceBus = bus.Advanced.Consume(queueName, registration => 
{
    registration.Add(typeof(MESSAGE1), info => { ProcessMessage(MESSAGE1) })    
    registration.Add(typeof(MESSAGE2), info => { ProcessMessage(MESSAGE2) })    
    registration.Add(typeof(MESSAGE3), info => { ProcessMessage(MESSAGE3) })    
});
```

In this way we can scan the assembly who uses this messages.

In other side, I register via construction of bus:

```
RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connectionString, registeredServices => {
IEasyNetQLogger logger;
MyCustomHandlerCollection myHandlers = myDIContainer.Resolve<IMyHandlers>();

registeredServices.Register<IHandlerCollection>(s => 
{ 
    logger = s.Resolve<IEasyNetQLogger>();
    return myHandlers;
});
registeredServices.Register<IHandlerRegistration>(s => myHandlers});});
```

But it not respecting my regisration because when I see the code from advance bus consuming:[consume code](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/master/Source/EasyNetQ/RabbitAdvancedBus.cs#L144) it creates from factory and NOT reading from container. I believe this is a root cause.

Answer (score 0):

To workaround this requirement, I used this method from IAdvanceBus :

```
IDisposable Consume(IQueue queue, Func<byte[], MessageProperties, MessageReceivedInfo, Task> onMessage);
```

I rolled my own message dispatcher and deserialize any message from the queue. The collection dispatcher will determine the message type and dispatch to specific handler created using reflection.